# Creating a unique ID from two 64-bit IDs

Tags: python, hash

Let's say I have two unique 64-bit IDs:

```
ID1 = 677313095844233279 
ID2 = 863850283313922058
```

. . . and I want to make a third unique ID generated from both of them. The ID generated from (ID1, ID2) should be the same as the one generated from (ID2, ID1).
The "easiest" way I could think of is just to merge the bits:

```
>>> (ID1 << 64) | ID2 

12494221336810479773180694257709350922
```

But the number here is kind of monstrous and isn't even the same both ways.

The second method is just to abuse Python's hash function with a frozenset:

```
>>> hash(frozenset({ID1, ID2})) 

-4995465307261022717
```

This number's a lot shorter, but I have no clue what's going on behind the scenes here.

What's the best "algorithm" to generate a not-too-big number?

Comment: Sort them, concatenate them, hash them with something like SHA1?

Comment: Don't even bother hashing, if you sort and concatenate them you now have a 128 bit id. Just note that you're asking for "a unique ID" and then immediately explain that you don't want unique IDs because new(ID1,ID2) should be the same as new(ID2,ID1), thus guaranteeing ID collision.

Comment: `ID1 ^ ID2`, if you don't need more than 64 bits in the combined hash.

Comment: @jasonharper would an XOR be unique? I figure numbers can have more than one pair of XOR "factors" (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I meant unique for that *pair*, I figured that was obvious.

Comment: @BENJAMINGILBERT You'll never had a "unique" result of two 64-bit numbers that result in one 64-bit number.  128 bits become 64 bits.  You'd need 127 bits to support all the unique combinations of two 64-bit numbers where the result is reversible.

Comment: @BENJAMINGILBERT the question talks about "unique" and "use hash" - those two things are not compatible - please re-read the question and make sure it matches your needs, I'd definitely recommend to [edit] it - be careful so with the edit as you idealy, should not invalidate an existing answer - but the answer does not satisfy "unique" part anyway, so may not be an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to XOR the 2 values with each other. Using Python's built-in xor function:

`NEWID = ID1 ^ ID2`.

This works by comparing each bit in each int and performing a logical XOR on each bit. If var1 = 1101 and var2 - 1001, the result will be 0110.

Note that if the 2 inputs have different lengths in binary some wrapping will occur, which could lead to some patterns in the outputs. This method should not be used if you need anything to be cryptographically secure. Additionally, this can be reversed if you XOR NEWID with either of the original values to get the 3rd value back: `NEWID ^ ID1 == ID2`

This tutorial https://teamtutorials.com/other-tutorials/how-to-xor-two-numbers-in-python has some more in-depth explanations if you want to read more.

Comment: If either one of ID1 or ID2 is zero then NEWID is the other. Not guaranteed to be unique.